# Wordpress show posts not on frontpage

Tags: wordpress

Apologies if this has been answered before, but I can't find it if it has. I'm new to wordpress and I'm a bit confused about how it treats posts as opposed to pages. The codex defines posts (http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Posts) as

> Posts are the entries that display in reverse chronological order on
>   your home page.

Well, that's fine *but* I don't want them displayed on my home page. I want them displayed on some other page (let's call it News) that is linked to from my home page.

This is surely something that is so common as to be boring but I can't find anything about doing this anywhere! I've tried custom page templates, wp_get_recent_posts(), and all sorts of other things, but nothing seems to quite work how I want. Besides, surely this is something that is so basic it must be staring me in the face?!?!

Comment: In the admin go to Settings > Reading and you can choose to display your posts on a static page instead of the front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *admin -> Settings -> Reading* and configure two static landing pages, e.g. a page called "Front" for your front page, and a page called "News" for blog posts.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something easy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FrontPage Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/frontpage-manager/). It can control main index page of wp.